# Stub not being called

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sinon, chai

I have a unit test for one of my controllers, which has a single function looking up data (sequelize) and adding the results as json to the response object.

I have two stubs, one of which is called the other is not.

Controller

```
exports.findAll =  (req, res) => {
    Idea.findAll().then(ideas => {
        console.log(ideas);
        return res.json(ideas);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Controller test

```
const chai = require('chai');
const {match, stub, resetHistory, spy} = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);

const {makeMockModels} = require('sequelize-test-helpers');

describe('Idea Controller', function () {

    const data = {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Stubbed Title',
        text: 'Stubbed text'
    };

    describe('findAll()', function () {
        it('Success case ', function () {

            const mockResponse = () => {
                const res = {};
                res.json = stub().returns(res);
                return res;
            };

            let res = mockResponse();

            const Idea = {findAll: stub()};
            const mockModels = makeMockModels({Idea});

            Idea.findAll.resolves(data);

            const ideaController = proxyquire('../../src/controllers/IdeaController', {
                '../models': mockModels
            });

            ideaController.findAll({}, res);

            Idea.findAll.should.have.been.called; // passes
            res.json.should.have.been.called; //fails
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: The problem could be because `findAll` is async. try to test inside `.then`

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the issue.  Moving the json assertion inside then solved the issue

Comment: Answer provided by @rkm should be marked as accepted if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `findAll` is async function you should move assertion inside `.then`.